# Simpler way to combine a if else statement (.contains?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list

what would be the best way to simplify this code. I thought about using .contains but I'm unsure how. Tell me if you need more code.

Thank you.

```
$.each(catalog.products,
      function(index, value) {

          if (filterValue == '' || value.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLocaleUpperCase()) != -1) {
              items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' +
                      '<a data-identity="productId"  href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' +
                      '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src="' + value.thumbnail + '"/>' +
                      '<p>' + value.brand + '</p>' +
                      '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' +
                      '<span class="ui-li-count">' + value.price + ' $</span></li>') +
              '</a>';
          }


          else if (filterValue == '' || value.brand.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLocaleUpperCase()) != -1) {
              items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' +
                      '<a data-identity="productId"  href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' +
                      '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src="' + value.thumbnail + '"/>' +
                      '<p>' + value.brand + '</p>' +
                      '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' +
                      '<span class="ui-li-count">' + value.price + ' $</span></li>') +
              '</a>';
          }
      }
        );
```

Comment: they are both the same except the second one says value.brand instead of value.name

Comment: `if (a||b){X} else if (a||c){X}` is equivalent to `if(a||b||c){X}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a simple addition of an `or` clause to the top if statement, or am I missing something?

Have you already tried this?

```
$.each(catalog.products,
  function(index, value) {

      if (filterValue == '' || value.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLocaleUpperCase()) != -1 || value.brand.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLocaleUpperCase()) != -1) {
          items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' +
                  '<a data-identity="productId"  href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' +
                  '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src="' + value.thumbnail + '"/>' +
                  '<p>' + value.brand + '</p>' +
                  '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' +
                  '<span class="ui-li-count">' + value.price + ' $</span></li>') +
          '</a>';
      }

  }
    );
```

Comment: Works... thanks. I thought I tried exactly this but something must've went wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Combine the conditional checks because you're pushing the same item for both code paths.

```
$.each(catalog.products, function(index, value) {
    var filter = filterValue.toLocaleUpperCase();

      if (filterValue == '' || value.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) != -1 || value.brand.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) != -1) {
          items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' +
                  '<a data-identity="productId"  href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' +
                  '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src="' + value.thumbnail + '"/>' +
                  '<p>' + value.brand + '</p>' +
                  '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' +
                  '<span class="ui-li-count">' + value.price + ' $</span></li>') +
          '</a>';
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something, both branches execute the same code. Why don't you just check both conditions in the first if (i.e. check whether value.name or value.brand contains filter value using an ||)?

Comment: They do. I tried the || at various places in my code but it seems I cant get it right. It looks so simple but yet i'm definitly missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should really be checking both conditions at the same time (both conditions execute the same code).  Second, if you need to, you could use the conditional operator:

```
variablename = (condition) ? value1 : value2;
```

You can even use it inline, if you wanted:

```
variablename = "this is a " + ((condition) ? value1 : value2) + " test";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

`$.each(catalog.products, function (index, value) {

        var filteredValue = filterValue != '' ? filterValue.toLocaleUpperCase() : '';`

```
    if (filterValue == '' || value.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filteredValue) != -1)
        items.push(getItem(index, value));
    else if (filterValue == '' || value.brand.toUpperCase().indexOf(filteredValue) != -1) 
        items.push(getItem(index, value));
}
```

);

`function getItem(index, value) { 

    return '<li id="' + index + '">' +

               <a data-identity="productId"  href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' +
                      '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src="' + value.thumbnail + '"/>' +
                      '<p>' + value.brand + '</p>' +
                      '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' +
                      '<span class="ui-li-count">' + value.price + ' $</span></li>') +

        '</a>';

}`